# How to Draw The View Controller with the Dyanamic Value

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

[image: ** **]

I have to make a view as image is below. I am confused and not able to darw  Screen as Screen will have more Image on Bottom of Image as User will scroll the  View and data on the Each time will come up Dynamically and Will on every time View Come up. Thanks any Help Appricated

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? Did you look at any tutorials/documentation? Take a look at `UITableView` class especially :)

Comment: Hello @Losiowaty i tried UITableView ,UICollectionView ,But  I am Confused is About that i Have to use UITableView for Each Section like upper middle and Bottom after That Whole view Will Not Scroll Together as i Know  as value will differs as well all time  guide me If i am Wrong Thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

after a long Research for this kind of view  Finally i got a Solution  Which is

> take a Table View 
>   take multiple Prototype Cell as much you Want 
>   Set the Identifier Individually of each cell 
>   create a Subcalss of UITableViewCell 
>   Method like callForRowatindexPath you have to call like That with Diffrent Cell

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  if indexPath.row == 0 {

       var  cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(kCellIdentifier) as? specificTopicTableViewCell`cell.textlabel.text = "Hello"
        return cell!
    }
        else  {
        let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(kSecCellIdentifier) as? scondTopicTableViewCell
       cell2.textlabel.text = "Hello"
          return cell2!
        }
}
```